# Cannot find TIF file

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

I'm trying to image a TIF file as a colormap but for some reason Python cannot seem to find the file I want it to image. I have installed matplotlib and Pillow.

Currently, these are the commands I'm giving it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mping
img=mping.imread('filename')
```

Although this doesn't image it as a colormap, I believe I saw on another post here that it could me modified into a colormap easily enough. Either way, this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in < module >

  File "C:\Users\query\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1417, in imread
    with Image.open(fname) as image:

  File "C:\Users\query\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the correct file directory as suggested by the error? `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'`. Using your command and setting the right file path the code work perfectly

Comment: Um. I could be wrong but did you *actually* use the literal file name `'filename'`? You are supposed to enter *your* filename there -- the name of an existing TIFF file, on your hard disk.

Comment: I didn't use that, I used the name of the file. I decided to replace the code and error message with "filename" because I didn't think the actual filename would matter.

Comment: Well, so can you share your real code and error without replacing the real file directory and file name? if it is this: `'C:\Users\query\Python pictures\Filename'` you must escape the backslash `'C:\\Users\\query\\Python pictures\\Filename'`

Comment: Alright, with all that it becomes 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.image as mping

img=mping.imread('C:\Users\\query\\Python pictures\Gaussian_magn_pos1')
`

With Gaussian_magn_pos1 being the filename.

If I make that 
`
img=mping.imread('C:\\Users\\query\\Python pictures\\Gaussian_magn_pos1')
`
It simply reverts to the "no such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the path of the file to the filename and use it in the function imread() or directly provide the filename to the function like imread('file.tif')

```
filename = 'file.tif'
```

and then:

```
imread(filename)
```

Comment: my bad. changed it.

Comment: If I do that, the  code becomes equivalent to this :
img=mping.imread('C:\Users\query\Python pictures\Filename')
This still gives me an error, namely: 

File "<stdin>", line 1 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Both the code above or the one you proposed give me this error.

Comment: a simple solution is to have the file and the code in the same directory and just read it like imread('file.tif')

Comment: This doesn't give an error but it also doesn't give me a figure. Code just runs and does nothing.

Comment: After more digging, it works! I got the image that I wanted, and it seems to have no problem finding the file anymore. Thanks! Now to find out how t oadd a colorbar and how to change the colorscale...

Answer (score 0):

For python to find the file you want to image you need to give it the filepath to your file, i'm going to assume that your file is not called `filename` and it actually has some extension so your function would be more like -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mping
img=mping.imread("source_data\\tif_files\\tif_data.tif")
```

Where you replace `"source_data\\tif_files\\tif_data.tif"` with the path to your file, either relative to where you call your script from or explicitly.

Comment: If I do that, the code becomes:
img=mping.imread('C:\Users\query\Python pictures\Filename')
However, it still gives me an error, namely:


File "<stdin>", line 1

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @justananimefan Did you remember to escape the `\\` you used in the string?